# Do I need to worry about bios settings when using a VM (XP)

Tags: virtualization, bios

I notice some of my BIOS settings were disabled or in legacy mode for better support (usually somewhere like the manual it says XP compatible). Do I have to worry about BIOS settings when running a VM?

I'll be running on Windows 7 and likely using VMWare. OS would be Windows XP (SP2 perhaps but i may have a SP3 somewhere) and various Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry. The BIOS on a virtual machine is independent from the BIOS on your real machine.

Just ensure that all the virtualization-related options on your BIOS are enabled and this should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that all of the Virtualization options in your BIOS are set correctly (on!).  But settings regarding drive configurations, etc are not applicable to the VM.